# Setting default theme

Tags: android

I started using Android Studio and I noticed that there was default theme Material Dark -> Material.

Some time later, after creating new project all Views disappeared from preview. I didn't know why, but finally I discovered that Theme changed to AppTheme.

And now I would like to set default Theme again to material. I see no option for that. A lot of google links direct me to set IDE Theme to IntelliJ or Darcula (this is not what I want to do).

In AndroidManifest.xml I can't get Material after writing Theme(dot)

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

minSdkVersion is set to 15, compileSdkVersion to 28.

Edit1: Everytime I add another view in Text mode, Theme changes to AppTheme. And then I see nothing on preview until I change Theme on Material.

How to set default Material Dark -> Material for my app projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define activity theme in Manifest. If you want to change theme for specific activity edit activity declaration like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</activity>
```

where AppTheme is your theme defined in styles.xml

If you want to set default theme for all activities, add **android:theme** to Application tag

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

where AppTheme is your theme from styles.xml.

These attributes will force preview to load your theme anytime.

Note: You should use **Theme.AppCompat** because of compatibility.

EDIT: I didn't read your question carefully. In manifest you can use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"` for material theme. Or better, for compatibility, `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`.

Comment: I still don't see Material Dark -> Material in `Theme.`

Comment: @pochmurnik see edit. Material theme must start with `@android:style/Theme.`